# stunned vs. astounded

Tags: meaning, difference

According to the Dictionary.com, `stunned` and `astounded` can be used interchangeably:

> Astound: to overwhelm with amazement; astonish greatly; shock with wonder or surprise.
>
> Stun: to make senseless, groggy, or dizzy by or as if by a blow; to shock; overwhelm.

Is it correct to say that `Astounded` is usually stronger and is a little bit about feelings and mental conditions whereas `Stunned` is often used with a physical situation?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "astound" isn't used for the physical sense. I think "stun", in the figurative sense of a psychological reaction, is actually stronger than "astound".
The word "astound" connotes very strong surprise, while "stun" in the figurative sense suggests a reaction similar to the effect of a physical blow, such as momentary paralysis.

Comment: Just a small addition:  I think in general "stunned" implies a more temporary condition than "astounded" as well.  People are usually only "stunned" briefly, but they can remain "astounded" for a long time.